# How can i find relative path location in CSS? Console.log in CSS?

Tags: html, css, console.log

so I'm working on this huge project (over 10000 lines of code) and i have this CSS file which i have to change.

I'm trying to add a relative path to one of my folders for a background image. I'm doing background: url("assets/header-logo.png");

But the problem is, I have no clue where this CSS file is being rendered.

is there a way to console.log in CSS somehow?

Comment: Where this file is being rendered? You mean the path where it is located??

Comment: No, you cannot console.log in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome browser, you can check the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) in the [Chrome Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to see what path is being picked up by the image, which can help debug this issue.